# Find out the elapsed time in each transformation in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

We can easily find the elapsed time for Job/stages in Spark UI but its difficult to find out the elapsed time for each transformation for that particular jobs.
is there any way to find out the elapsed time for each transformation such as select--19 sec...groupby--12sec--join--48sec like that.
Could you please review it and provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the profiling you are trying to do is possible with Spark.
Just one important point that you may be missing here: the code you are passing to Spark and the operation Spark is doing to calculate can be different.

To help you understand, Here is a good article:
[understanding-sparks-logical-and-physical-plan](https://blog.knoldus.com/understanding-sparks-logical-and-physical-plan-in-laymans-term/)

In shorter words, the transformations you are doing can be optimized, an extream example could be that your transformation is removed from the final physical plan,  which makes it impossible to trace the elapsed time.